# Speeding up HTML5 Canvas Brush drawing onMouseMove

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently trying to create brushes which draw on a Canvas HTML-Element. They should in the end work kind of like Photoshop-Brushes: Click - Move - Release results in a line along the mouse movement.

I have implemented a very primitive brush, however this gets really slow very quickly, [**here is a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aesthaddicts/PEKyw/). Try drawing multiple strokes or a very long one and you'll see that the distance of captured points gets much larger. Probably this behavior results from clearing the whole canvas and iterating through all of the saved points, but I'm not quite sure what a better approach would look like. Here is the main drawing code:

```
// while moving the mouse, each captured point gets saved into
// a multi-dimensional array of strokes; then, at each event
// (mousemove, mousedown and mouseup) this function is called

PrimitiveBrush.prototype._draw = function () {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.width, this.ctx.height)

    for (var i = 0, l = this.strokes.length; i < l; i++) {
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.strokes[i][0].x, this.strokes[i][0].y);
        for (var j = 1, m = this.strokes[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            var point = this.strokes[i][j];
            this.ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    this.ctx.stroke();
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a FIDDLE Demo?

Comment: I tried to right here: http://jsfiddle.net/aesthaddicts/PEKyw/ However it doesn't seem to bind the mouse events? =/ New to jsfiddle so I couldn't figure it out, no matter what I tried…

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the JSFiddle and inserted the link! :)

Comment: That's because you're generating thousands of points, check for some distance from the last point created before adding another one. Though this would disable creation of very fine shapes...

Comment: @Kroltan Tahnks for the suggestion, I already considered this. However, there are multiple problems with this: First, as you already said, more distance between points means loss in quality; Second, it's hard to determine a good distance to pick, as that would be dependant on the user's computer. If I picked 2px minimum distance it could still slow down quickly on slower systems than mine. It would be perfect if there is a solution that changes the drawing algorithm in a way that it doesn't have to re-draw and iterate through all pixels each time, but I'm not sure how to approach that

Comment: @aesthaddicts A common technique in professional programs (such as Adobe Flash Studio) is to draw a low-quality example of how the brush will be applied while it is being drawn (for example: no antialiasing, etc) and only draw the full resolution brush when the mouse is released. However this would still impact performance with multiple strokes because only the current stroke will be simplified. You might also want to consider _not_ clearing the canvas and redrawing, since your shapes don't move, and only draw the latest segment. Using both would add a giant performance boost to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you're caching points from mousemove and drawing them inside requestAnimationFrame.

Nice!

That separates the mousemove capturing from the drawing which results in drawing that's well coordinated with screen refreshes.

**Some suggested refactoring:**

- Don't clear the canvas with every draw
- Use beginPath to avoid repeated over-draws of existing segments
- Only draw the most recent points added

So instead of drawing every point-array in this.strokes, just draw the last point-array.

For even better performance, just draw the undrawn points in the last point-array.

Optionally (In this.end): clear the canvas and redraw all the points for a clearer looking final drawing.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wAGcL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get reference to canvas and save canvas offsets
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    var offsetX=canvas.offsetLeft;
    var offsetY=canvas.offsetTop;

    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

    /**
     * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} context
     */
    function PrimitiveBrush(context) {
        if (!(context instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)) {
            throw new Error('No 2D rendering context given!');
        }

        this.ctx = context;
        this.strokes = [];
        this.strokeIndex=0;
        this.workingStrokes=[];
        this.lastLength=0;
        this.isTouching = false;

        // init context
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
        this.ctx.lineWidth = '3';
        this.ctx.lineCap = this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

        // start the drawing loop
        this._draw();
    }

    /**
     * Begins a new stroke
     * @param  {MouseEvent} event
     */
    PrimitiveBrush.prototype.start = function (event) {
        var x=event.clientX-offsetX;
        var y=event.clientY-offsetY;
        this.workingStrokes=[{x:x,y:y}];
        this.strokes.push(this.workingStrokes);
        this.lastLength=1;
        this.isTouching = true;
    };

    /**
     * Moves the current position of our brush
     * @param  {MouseEvent} event
     */
    PrimitiveBrush.prototype.move = function (event) {
        if(!this.isTouching){return;}
        var x=event.clientX-offsetX;
        var y=event.clientY-offsetY;
        this.workingStrokes.push({x:x,y:y});
    };

    /**
     * Stops a stroke
     * @param  {MouseEvent} event
     */
    PrimitiveBrush.prototype.end = function (event, foo) {
        this.move(event);
        this.isTouching = false;
    };

    PrimitiveBrush.prototype._draw = function () {

        requestAnimationFrame(this._draw.bind(this));

        // save the current length quickly (it's dynamic)
        var length=this.workingStrokes.length;

        // return if there's no work to do
        if(length<=this.lastLength){return;}

        var startIndex=this.lastLength-1;

        this.lastLength=length;

        var pt0=this.workingStrokes[startIndex];

        this.ctx.beginPath();

        this.ctx.moveTo(pt0.x,pt0.y);

        for(var j=startIndex;j<this.lastLength;j++){

            var pt=this.workingStrokes[j];

            this.ctx.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);

        }

        this.ctx.stroke();

    };

    // Set up brush to listen to events
    var brush = new PrimitiveBrush(canvas.getContext('2d'));

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', brush.start.bind(brush));
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', brush.move.bind(brush));
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', brush.end.bind(brush));

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="drawing" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**Also just a point of performance:**  Calling makePoint reduces performance.

- cache canvas.offsetLeft/canvas.offsetTop
- create point object in the same function it's needed

Comment: Thanks for the response. By chance, are you open to consulting on a simple canvas application? Happy to share more details.

Comment: @Crashalot, Sure, if the app is interesting. Contact: MarksPublicAddress@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can achieve a faster line drawing:

**For method 1:** (recommended)

- Create a new canvas that you place on top of the main
- When you draw draw to the top canvas
- When mouse is released transfer the drawn points to the main canvas and store the points, and clear top canvas

If you need or want to be able to draw very long lines you can always split in between and do a transfer to reduce the number of points redrawn.

**For method 2:**

A little lower quality when you draw as the line ends are separated but it will be fixed on mouse up:

- Store last mouse position on mouse down
- On mouse move draw a line between last point and current point
- Update current point after each line is drawn
- On mouse up redraw all to make lines continuous

A very short example of the principle (pseudo code):

```
var lastX, lastY, isDown = false, ...

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var pos = getXY(e); // get mouse position somehow
    isDown = true;

    lastX = pos.x;
    lastY = pos.y:
]

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    if (!isDown) return;

    var pos = getXY(e); // get mouse position somehow

    drawLine(lastX, lastY, pos.x, pos.y);

    points.push(pos);   // store point somewhere

    lastX = pos.x;
    lastY = pos.y:
]
```

etc.

Another thing you can fix right away in your current code is to insert a `beginPath()` in your `_draw()` method. Just doing that will increase the speed as what is happening now is that you accumulate every point to the current path and for each new point you are drawing all the path vectors with all previous lines and also redrawn as well as the points you redraw in the loop (this means that there is an exponential amount to redraw for each new point).

```
PrimitiveBrush.prototype._draw = function () {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.ctx.width, this.ctx.height)

    this.ctx.beginPath();  // insert here

    for (var i = 0, l = this.strokes.length; i < l; i++) {
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.strokes[i][0].x, this.strokes[i][0].y);
        for (var j = 1, m = this.strokes[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            var point = this.strokes[i][j];
            this.ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    this.ctx.stroke();
};
```

But it will not solve the main problem - for that consider using one of the two methods mentioned.

Hope this helps.